# Overriding Responsive Row Defaults in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a structure that looks like this:

```
<div class="row row-phone">
  <div class="span3 span3-phone">
  <div class="span3 span3-phone">
  <div class="span3 span3-phone">
  <div class="span3 span3-phone">
</div>
<div class="row row-phone">
  <div class="span3 span3-phone">
  <div class="span3 span3-phone">
  <div class="span3 span3-phone">
  <div class="span3 span3-phone">
</div>
```

The span3-phone CSS is a responsive class that makes the divs take up 32% of their container instead of whatever span3 usually takes up. The CSS is simple:

```
.span-3-phone {

  width: 32%;
}
```

This adjusts their width fine. The problem is that the presence of the row class breaks the divs up after the 4th div, whereas I want 3 divs per row. Is there any way to override the function of row for mobile devices so that it doesn't break the elements up? Without being able to do that it seems I will have to create an entirely different HTML document, which is not what I want.

Comment: Have you looked at the [new grid system in Boostrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)? It provides a new functionality like the one you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

You can over ride CSS by the use of `!important`. There are time when it's use is abused and considered lazy. It is a good solution when CSS needs over written and no other option is viable. A good example would be the use of `!important` when a javascript plugin is generating inline CSs and you need to overwrite it and you do not have the option to edit the plugin. If the one single use of `!important` would prevent you from having to re-write your entire `html` then i'd suggest it's use.

```
.span-3-phone {    
    width: 32% !important;
}
```